# 404 Error when trying to get the photos from Google Map API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
renderPhotos(place) {
    if (!place.photos || place.photos.length == 0) return;

    const cfg = {maxWidth: 100, maxHeight: 100}
    return (<div className={styles.photoStrip}>
      {place.photos.map(p => {
        const url = `${p.getUrl(cfg)}.png`
        return (<img key={url} src={url} />)
      })}
    </div>)
  }
```

I receive this error: AF1QipOcxB_SbhXOWZVkrw15sBppOigDEgl1fcvMtpqv=w100-h100-k.png:1 GET https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipOcxB_SbhXOWZVkrw15sBppOigDEgl1fcvMtpqv=w100-h100-k.png 404 ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the ".png" file extension in the URL and it should work :)

```
const url = `${p.getUrl(cfg)}`
```

not

```
const url = p.getUrl(cfg);
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasted 3 hours trying to figure what was the problem.

Comment: You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if this solves your problem